# Trying to access one class from another

Tags: python-3.x, class, variables

Just started learning Python and trying to understand OOP. In the first class I've got a buffer with integers and in the second class I'm trying to access a buffer from a first class. The part of code is below:

```
class Buffer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = []

    def push(self, value):
        self.lst.append(value)

        if len(self.lst) == 5:
            #print(self.lst)
            print("I: " + str(self.lst[0]/10) + " Rpm: " + str(self.lst[1]) + " Pwm: " + str(self.lst[2]) + " T: " + str(self.lst[3]) + " V: " + str(self.lst[4]/10))
            self.lst = self.lst[5:]

class Log(Buffer):
    def __init__(self):
        path = "/home/pi/Desktop/test.txt"
        self.log = open(path, "a")

    def write(self):
        self.log.write("I: " + str(self.lst[0]/10) + " Rpm: " + str(self.lst[1]) + " Pwm: " + str(self.lst[2]) + " T: " + str(self.lst[3]) + " V: " + str(self.lst[4]/10))

    def close(self):
        self.log.close()

buffer = Buffer()
log = Log()
```

However when I'm trying to run the code, I'm getting an `AttributeError.` It means that I'm accessing from one class to another wrong. What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: [might be helpful](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=from%20io%20import%20StringIO%0Aclass%20Buffer%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20__init__%28self%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.lst%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0Aclass%20Log%28Buffer%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20__init__%28self%29%3A%0A%23%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super%28%29.__init__%28%29%0A%23!!!%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%20PART%20YOU%20ARE%20MISSING%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.log%20%3D%20StringIO%28%29%0Alog%20%3D%20Log%28%29%0A%23pythontutor_hide%3A%20StringIO)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A call to the constructor of the super class is missing in the `Log` class which is why `lst` is no attribute of `Log` when using it in `write`.

```
class Log(Buffer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...
```